# Oracle - Delete records with conditions

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to write SQL which deletes records based on a few conditions.

I have four records[image: image of records]

In these records, ID is unique and can change. Name is used to delete the records.

1) A Name should have at least one OK type.

2) IF Name has an ID that doesn't contain DUMMY in its name, then delete all other records where ID contains DUMMY.

How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: How does "A Name should have at least one OK type" come into play? How is this supposed to affect whether or not or which rows we delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
delete from tablename t
where t."id" like '%DUMMY%'
and t."name" = (
  select "name" from tablename
  where "name" = '?'
  group by "name"
  having sum(case when "type" = 'OK' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
  and sum(case when "id" not like '%DUMMY%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
)
```

The subquery after the `IN` clause returns the `name`s that have at least 1 `type = 'OK'` and at least 1 `id` not containing `'DUMMY'`. 
Edit:

```
delete from tablename t
where
  t."name" = '?' 
  and (
    (t."id" like '%DUMMY%' and t."type" <> 'OK')
    or (
      t."type" = 'OK' 
      and exists (
        select 1 from tablename
        where "name" = t."name" and "type" = t."type" and "id" > t."id"
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: hi, I want to pass name, I don't want to do it for all names. How can I do that ?

Comment: Hi, It is not working right. it is deleting all OK records if the name is DUMMY. I need at least one OK record

Comment: I think you did not explain fully what you want. What does *A Name should have at least one OK type* mean? That the row with OK should not be deleted?

Comment: *IF Name has an ID that doesn't contain DUMMY in its name, then delete all other records where ID contains DUMMY.* doesn't this mean delete all rows except the one without DUMMY in id?

Comment: yes - It there are two OK records and both ID contains dummy, only one record should be deleted.

Comment: I have two scenarios, I want to implement in that order. I now edit my first post

Comment: Post sample data in text form covering all possible cases, also expected results and explain the results.

Comment: I posted in the above screenshot, thats why I put two OK records. I just want to delete one of them if ID contains DUMMY

Comment: This covers 1 case. If there is a row with OK and another row without dummy then which row should be deleted? If there is not any row with OK and not any row without DUMMY what should be deleted?

Comment: at least one OK record should be there, that means in your first question, none of the records should be deleted. For your second quetions, Not any row with OK is not possible.

Comment: So to sum up: if there is an id without DUMMY then it is not deleted. Also if there is only 1 OK with DUMMY or without DUMMY it is not deleted. All the other rows that contain DUMMY or are OK above the first one should be deleted, right?

Comment: I am confused by this line where "name" = t."name" and "type" = t."type" and "id" > t."id"

Comment: This condition makes sure that all rows with OK will be deleted except that row with the maximum id. I chose the maximum to not be deleted because you mention: *A Name should have at least one OK type* so I guess it does not matter which OK will not be deleted.

Comment: The condition `"id" > t."id"` is there to make sure that only 1 type OK will remain. If there are 2 of them then 1 will be deleted.

Comment: i think it is because of the comparison. in string comparison, it is only taking the lowest alphabet. You take id as integer I think

Comment: It does not matter which one remains, right? So the comparison just makes sure which one will remain.

Comment: yes, it doesnt matter but lets see the id value starts with E and in comparison with Dummy, it is picking the value that starts with E not dummy

Comment: Your 1st requirement is: *A Name should have at least one OK type* so what is the problem if it deletes the one starting with E or the one with dummy?

Comment: if it is other than dummy, means it is valid value. then delete dummy. If it dont contain dummy, then delete all dummy except 1

Comment: This is not the requirement you posted in your question.

Comment: Your 2nd condition is NOT about OK. My condition:       t."type" = 'OK' 
      and exists (
        select 1 from tablename
        where "name" = t."name" and "type" = t."type" and "id" > t."id" is about OK.

Comment: my second condition applies to all including Ok.

Comment: Then you did not explain correctly all your requirements.

Comment: sorry for that but I am thinking it is because of string comparison with Id.